# How to SUM columns with Currency (object type) values in Python / Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

df

| Product | Price | Tax |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Fork | U$ 14,00 | U$ 0,40 |
| Knife | U$ 23,00 | U$ 0,85 |
| Knife | U$ 23,00 | U$ 0,91 |
| Knife | U$ 23,00 | U$ 0,77 |

```
df_sum_price = df['Price'].sum()
df_sum_tax = df['Tax'].sum()
df_sum_price 
df_sum_tax
```

output wanted:

```
>>> U$ 83,00
U$ 2,93
```

HOW CAN I DO THIS? Because i need before convert Object to Int or Float but i don't know why! .-. help me please

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is no currency type in Python. I guess your "Price" column is a string? The first operation would be to turn this column into a float. To do so, you have to remove the "U$ " in front of the digits, and then turn the "," into "." to be able to turn your string into a float. So a function doing that would be:

```
def price_to_float(price):
    return(float(price[3:].replace(',','.')))`
```

Then, just apply this function to your whole column with:

```
df['Price']=df.apply(lambda row : price_to_float(row['Price']), axis = 1)
df['Tax']=df.apply(lambda row : price_to_float(row['Price']), axis = 1)
```

Now you can perform all the operations you want to! You can then turn your column back to a currency string if you need to.

Comment: great answer but apply function should be rarely used. It would cost a lot when used on huge dataframes.

Comment: You are right! Your answer was better

Answer (score 1):

if you have an option to convert datatype in dataframe the you can do this

```
df['Tax']=(df['Tax'].str[3:]).str.replace(',','').astype(int)
df['Price']=(df['Price'].str[3:]).str.replace(',','').astype(int)

output:

  Product  Price  Tax
0    Fork   1400   40
1   Knife   2300   85
2   Knife   2300   91
3   Knife   2300   77

df_sum_price = df['Price'].sum()
df_sum_tax = df['Tax'].sum()
df_sum_price 
df_sum_tax 

output:

8300
293
```

if you dont have the freedom to change datatype and just want to perform the sum then do this:

```
df_sum_price = (df['Tax'].str[3:]).str.replace(',','').astype(int).sum()
df_sum_tax = (df['Price'].str[3:]).str.replace(',','').astype(int).sum()
df_sum_price 
df_sum_tax
```

output is same in both the cases.

Comment: It doens't working with Object type... or i'm making cheat .-.

Comment: Currency is not a data type in pandas dataframe if you want to print it in that way do this. print('U$ '+str((df['Price'].str[3:]).str.replace(',','').astype(int).sum())) this should print sum for price column.

Comment: Do upvote and accept the solution if you found answer helpful